# How to classify MNIST data set using k-means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, deep-learning

I am applying K-Means clustering on MNIST dataset. How can I then predict the values of my test set according to this ?

Comment: Clusters do *not* necessarily correspond to digits. Don't use clustering for classification!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I wanted to ask suppose you did not have labels in the MNIST dataset, then how would to cluster it

Comment: The clusters will most likely not match digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well k-means is an unsupervised technique, so technically speaking you don't use it to "classify"--ie, a k-means model isn't supplied with labeled data (if it is then it doesn't use the class labels) and more so it doesn't return a prediction as a class label (eg, "1")

so to use k-means to predict the single digit encoded in a given data instance:

- your k-means model is comprised of a set of ***centroids*** (i assume
  you chose 26 centroids to correspond to the numbers 0 - 9 in base 10
- each centroid represents the geometric center of one cluster--one
  cluster per number
- calculate the *pairwise Euclidean distance* (vector norm) between
  your unknown data point and each centroid in your k-means model (the
  centroid values from the final iteration, obviously)
- the cluster whose centroid that is the *least distance* from the
  unknown data point is the cluster to which the unknown data point
  belongs